# Sharing a global variable from database result to the view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, continuous-integration

In my header and in the footer are some dynamic navigations from the database. So i need a result from the database on each site in Laravel.

In Laravel's documentation under [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) is the way descripted.

So i created the Query in the `AppServiceProvider` under `boot()`:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $navigation = \App\Navigation::all();
        view()->share('navigation', $navigation);
    }

    // ...
}
```

It works, but i work with CI and everytime the tests are failing

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> [ -f /usr/bin/php71 ] && /usr/bin/php71 artisan optimize || php artisan optimize

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                         
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.navigation' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `navigation`)                                                                       

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.navigation' doesn't exist                                                      

[PDOException]                                                               
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.navigation' doesn't exist
```

It's because the tables are not migrated at this time...

So i catch the Exception like this:

```
try {
    $navigation = \App\Navigation::all();
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    $navigation = [];
}
view()->share('navigation', $navigation);
```

Is this the right way or is there a better way to share a database result to the view?

Answer (score 1):

You have this because your database is not migrated yet.

Use `composer` instead of `share`, that way the closure (or a ViewComposer class) will be called when the data is really needed and not at the startup of your app.

See the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers).